Can a ratio $\lim_{x \to c} f'(x)/f(x)$ of a derivative and a function be defined at $c$ when both are zero?
Given a differentiable function $f$ where $f(c) = 0$ for some $c$, can $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ have a defined value?
I guess $f'(c)$ should also be zero for this to possibly have a value, but I'm stuck here.
(This is not a homework problem; one of my colleagues studying NN asked me)

Assume $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ exists, then we say in a small neighbourhood $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=g(x)$, since $f(x)$ can not be identically zero on this small neighbourhood, then the solution to this differential equation is $f(x)=e^{\int^x g(x)dx}$, which cannot be zero.

Hello. I appreciate the effort in constructing the proof, but I believe it requires additional rigor and precision, especially in the concluding argument. Consider the function f(x) = x^2, which can be viewed as a solution to the differential equation f'/f =g(x) with the initial condition f(0) = 0. For x!=0, we indeed have f=e^\int 2/xdx = e^2ln|x| = x^2, ,aligning with your solution form. However, this function clearly satisfies f(0) = 0, which seems to contradict the assertion that f(x) cannot be zero under the given  assumptions.

Yeah, I should say more about the continuity of g(x). Since the limit of f'/f exists as x tends to c, we can extend g(x) to this point c continuously. Thus we can view g(x) as a continuous function on a small neighborhood of c, thus the solution should be a well-behaved function. In your case, 2/x is not continuous at 0, the limit of f'/f does exist, then the solution to this differential equation may behave badly at this point.
